# Using new statement in JPQL request

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I use `new` in JPQL query like the following way

```sql
select 
  ob.property1,
  NEW package1.CustomObject(item, dimension, material, product)
from mainTable ob
LEFT JOIN ....
```

The application complains about the coma after `ob.property1` saying it is an unexpected token. It seems that you cannot use multiple column with a `new` inside the select clause. Can you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause) you have the following options:

1. Wrapping the values in a type-safe Java object that will be returned as the results of the query.

```
select new package1.CustomObject(item, dimension, material, product)
from MainTable ...
```

> The projection class must be fully qualified in the entity query, and it must define a matching constructor. The class here need not be mapped. It can be a DTO class. If it does represent an entity, the resulting instances are returned in the NEW state (not managed!).

**HQL** supports additional "dynamic instantiation" features.

2. The query can specify to return a `List` rather than an `Object[]` for scalar results.

```
select new list(item, dimension, material, product)
from MainTable ...
```

> The results from this query will be a `List<List>` as opposed to a `List<Object[]>`.

3. Wrapping the scalar results in a `Map`

```
select new map(
  item as iName,
  dimension as iDimension,
  material as iMaterial,
  product as iProduct)
from MainTable ...
```

> The results from this query will be a `List<Map<String, Object>>` as opposed to a `List<Object[]>`. The keys of the map are defined by the aliases given to the select expressions. If the user doesn’t assign aliases, the key will be the index of each particular result set column (e.g. 0, 1, 2, etc).